# When should an order be created in a webshop

Tags: c#, design, .net

Let's say I want to make a webshop, which sells custom mugs (for the sake of simplicity). In the shop, you go through 3 steps:

1. Select cup size
2. Select color
3. Add a logo

And then finally it is added to a basket, which then leads to a check out procedure. That means that there, at some point, will be a class *Order*, which contains *Order Lines*. The *Order* also contains a *Customer* whom should reviece his/her mug.

**My question is this:** Is there some sort of standard for how to solve this (like a "design pattern")? Should it be at the very beginning of creating the first mug? Or should I store all the mugs (which are also classes) somewhere else, until checkout and then move them to the order? This isn't just about finding "any" solution. But rather, if a solution to the problem already exists (I cannot be the first one to have this issue).

**Edit:** Just to make it more confusing. There is also a scenario, where you can create 3 different mugs, compare them, and then only select the one you like better. How does this affect my issue?

**Edit 2:**

If I were to ask the question again, I would ask something like: "How to use customizable objects in a shopping cart/order". And the answer to myself would be to 'complete' the object first, then add it to a cart and don't even start thinking about orders, until the shopping is complete. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi Noceo. I'm afraid this question is too broad. As you said, there several approaches that could work. Doesn't matter how many of them are out there, the one you need is the one that best fit in your requirements and needs and we know nothing about them, in consequence the answers are going to be mainly opinion based.

Comment: @Laiv you might be right. What I wanted to know was, if there was some sort of "rules" regarding this. I mean design patters (MVC, MVVM, etc.) aren't excactly required either. It just happended, that at some point, someone figured out that solving the same problem over and over again, didn't really make much sense. So I guess you could say, that I am looking for some sort of design pattern for order management in software...

Comment: Sorry to say but there's not. Order management pretty much depens on your real business strategy and organization. The model changes from project to project and from shop to shop.

Comment: My humble advice. Please, clarify the business first before thinking about the implementation details (classes, patterns, etc). The most important thing here is not *How my software looks like* or *How it does what it does*. The most important thing is **what it does and why**! Get clear first what you want to do. Gather requirements first (a good bunch) and then (progressively) start working on "how to take them forward". The how is the lesser of the problems. Btw the "what" and the "why" will lead you to well-known patterns or just lead to new ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a shopping cart, containing the details of the future order, and only create the actual order once payment has been received (or at least guaranteed by a broker).

That way there is no way that an order can get processed, fulfilled, and shipped to a customer who hasn't paid (or maybe doesn't even finalise the ordering process by confirming his intent to place the order, which is the bulk of web shop traffic, people just browsing).

What you want in a web shop is strict isolation of the shop and the underlying warehouse and manufacturing systems, for exactly that reason, the majority of activity in the shop never leads to a firm order that actually needs to enter the backend systems at all.

Comment: So something like creating two container classes: `Basket` and `Order`. And then moving stuff like customer information, order lines, etc. from `Basket` to `Order` upon check out completion?

Comment: Payment on delivery (by cash) is quite popular in many countries.

Comment: @isarandi true, but in that case the user should still complete all the required steps, including his address information and giving approval for that (which usually incurs an extra charge and thus an extra orderline) before the order is accepted for processing. And it'd not be acceptable (except maybe for trusted repeat customers) for custom work as seems implied from the original question, as that work'd probably not be able to be sold to another customer if the original were incapable or unwilling to take delivery.

Comment: @Noceo something like that. Most likely you'd also have to have a process that notifies external systems of the order, like your warehouse application, billing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you want to keep the mugs on a separate holder just not to create the order. You should create the order as soon as you know that the customer intends to make one, it could be on the moment he initiates the session or on the moment he selects the first mug. If you created a different holder for the mugs previous to creating the order you're creating an object that has no further use and you need to implement some logic for you to transfer the mugs from the temporary object to the actual order. You'd be better of disposing the order if the user cancels it.

UPDATE:

Regarding the case that you mention with the comparison, I'd have a comparer option for that with its specific backend and UI. From the comparer the customer should have the option to select any of them (or all of them).

Comment: Good point. I edited the post, as there is an additonal scenario, in which the customer has the option to create 3 mugs and compare them (before selecting one). Should I then add all 3 mugs to the order, and remove the two he/she does not like?

Answer (score 0):

The order is created at checkout. Regardless of payment.
Once checkout is done the details of an order are set.

Think about it like this: 
Let's say your shop is running a daily discount. What you don't want is having people put discounted items into a digital shopping basket and have them sit there for days/weeks after the discount ended and still get the items at a discounted rate.

On the other hand, with the same discount, once someone has actually ordered your discounted item (checkout) you can't charge him the normal rate even if for some instance the order gets processed after the discount date.

So at checkout time.

Also remember that at that time you "disconnect" your order from your relational data. This is very important. You don't want a price update to also effect checked out orders.